# Intent filter for call phone number not working

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want to list my app in "Complete action using" dialog when user call a phone number. I found following answer in SO which is working for others

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
```

with permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />`

but it doesn't work for me, May be i am missing something. I am testing this in andorid 5(lollipop).

Answer (score 0):

use 
      `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       </intent-filter>`